# Flutter Listview: how to achieve the equivalent of Column CrossAxisAlignment.end?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a vertical list of widgets to show and I want the very last one (a `TextButton`) to be aligned to the right of the screen. Normally, this can easily be achieved with `CrossAxisAlignment.end` in a `Column`,  but I need it to be scrollable so I am using `ListView`. Children in `ListView` seem to always be automatically centered, but I want this last widget to be aligned to the right. How can I achieve this?

**What I want**: The `TextButton` is aligned to the right (this picture was done using a `Column`):

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    TextButton(child: const Text('Tap me'), onPressed: (){}), 
  ])
```

[image]

What I currently get using a `ListView`:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    TextButton(child: const Text('Tap me'), onPressed: (){}),
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the ButtonStyle attribute in Flutter buttons to modify alignment of children:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    TextButton(
      child: const Text('Tap me'), 
      onPressed: (){}, 
      style: ButtonStyle(
         alignment: Alignment.centerRight
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your widget `Align( alignment: Alignment.centerRight,`

```dart
body: ListView(
children: [
  const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
  const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
  const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
  Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: TextButton(child: const Text('Tap me'), onPressed: () {})),
],
)
```

More about [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TextButton` in a `Row` and set the `Row`'s mainAxisAlignment to end. This should make the `TextButton` aligned to the right as you want.

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    const ListTile(title: Text('Title'), subtitle: Text('Subtitle')),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [TextButton(child: const Text('Tap me'), onPressed: (){})],
    ),
  ],
),
```